# Calling /me/contacts/{id}/photo does not return eTag

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am calling the `me/contacts/{id}/photo` and the responses do not match what is [defined in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#response-3).

According to the docs, two things do not match what I am seeing:

1. When a contact does not have a photo it states that you will receive an empty json paylod, however I am getting a `404` response back with this error

   ```
   Code: ErrorItemNotFound
   Message: The specified object was not found in the store.
   ```
2. When there is a photo for a contact, the article states there will be a `@odata.mediaEtag`, however the payload I am receiving back does not have one. Below is my response:

   ```
   (*map[string]interface {})(0xc42014a028)((len=5) {
    (string) (len=6) "height": (float64) 360,
    (string) (len=5) "width": (float64) 360,
    (string) (len=14) "@odata.context": (string) (len=243) "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('REDACTED')/contacts('REDACTED')/photo/$entity",
    (string) (len=23) "@odata.mediaContentType": (string) (len=10) "image/jpeg",
    (string) (len=2) "id": (string) (len=7) "360X360"
   })
   ```

Issue #1 is does not impact me as I can easily handle a `404`. I am more concerned with issue #2 as I would like the `etag` so I can track whether or not the image has been changed and only download it when it has been changed.

I was able to setup OAuth, get the APIs working, and successfully download contacts and photos following the docs, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Different endpoints may return slightly different data (i.e. `/me/photo` vs `/me/{id}/photo` vs `/groups/{id}/photo`). The only properties you can be sure will be there are specied by the [`profilePhoto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profilephoto?view=graph-rest-1.0) resoruce:

```
{
  "id": "240X240",
  "height": 240,
  "width": 240
}
```

You may be able to use the `eTag` for the `contact` itself (changing a contact's photo in Outlook should show up as a modification to the contact) using `/me/contacts/{id}?$select=id,lastModifiedDateTime`:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{id}')/contacts(id,lastModifiedDateTime)/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"EQAAABYAAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e/T7KzowPTAAAYc8Bf\"",
    "id": "{id}",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-09-04T15:54:02Z"
}
```